# Destination store in variable instead of cell

Tags: excel, vba

My current code below adds the site string to a sheet and then references the cell to work out what country the code applies to.

Is it possible to just extract the information from the query without having to add it to a sheet, so that I can apply it later on in my code?

Therefore instead of "Destination:=Range("A2") can I get it straight into "pc" to then check the site string

```
    Const SITE = "SELECT site_id FROM site WHERE category = 'ID001' "

Set rs = conn.Execute(SITE)

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A2"))
    .Refresh
End With

Range("A1").Select
Dim pc As String
    pc = Cells(2, 1)

If InStr(1, pc, "Z") = 1 Then
    pc = "NI"
ElseIf InStr(1, pc, "W") = 1 Then
    pc = "Wales"
ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(pc, 1)) Then
    pc = "Scotland"
Else
    pc = "England"
End If
```

Comment: I have a very basic knowledge of VBA, but I don't really want to have to enter the value of the query in a cell - to then check it and then delete the cell. I'd just want the value of the query, so I can check it directly without the need to create a sheet and reference the cell in the sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want you `pc` variable to be the first value in the `Recordset` object `rs`. Try directly without using any `QueryTables`:

```
Set rs = conn.Execute(SITE)
Dim pc As String
pc = rs.Fields(0).Value
```

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you so much